# VBA keep row based on a name and time and delete older entries

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following data in Excel (created for the example), where in the rightest column "Key" is my target. I would like to keep only top row for each name and delete older entries with the same name, based on date & time. Thus, I would like to keep only green rows i.e., Apple Big 14:14:50 and delete the one below.

I have problem how the code should distinguish between names and limited idea how to tell my VBA code that all other rows with the same name just delete.
My data:
[image: data]

My idea, it's not a full code, only idea:

```
Dim LR As Long

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & LR)

If A = "Key" Then Delete.Row
Else "Move one cell down" and set cell = "Key"



End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a possibility that (for example), AppleBig appear again under PearSmall, but with different date and time ? Or is the table (in the picture you attached) already in a sorted condition? ---> Three level sorting : Key, then RecordDate then Time.

Comment: It's sorted. So no chance that AppleBig appear again under PearSmall.

Comment: If your data starts in `A1` and is sorted like in the screenshot, a simple [RemoveDuplicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates) should do: `Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion: rg.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes` keeping just the first occurrence of each `Key`. Let us know if that's not the case.

Comment: It looks like it works. Wow. That simple. I'm double checking

Answer (score 1):

### Remove Duplicates Using a Dictionary

[image]

- If your data is not sorted, you can't use `RemoveDuplicates` but you could use the following procedure.
- The star of the show is a dictionary whose *keys* will hold the unique values from the 1st column (`Keys`) and whose *items* will hold a two-element array, whose 1st element will hold the row index while the 2nd element will hold the value retrieved by adding the values from the 3rd and 4th columns. On each iteration, the new 2nd value (`cValue`) will be checked against the old value and the old data will be replaced with the new data if the new 2nd value is greater than the old.

```vb
Sub RemoveDupes()
    
    Const UNIQUE_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 1 ' CStr
    Const DATE_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 3 ' IsDate
    Const TIME_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 4 ' IsNumeric
    Const COPY_VALUES_ONLY As Boolean = False
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    Set rg = rg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1) ' data without headers
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    Dim Arr() As Double: ReDim Arr(1 To 2)
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim cString As String
    Dim cValue As Double
    Dim IsValid As Boolean
    Dim DontWrite As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        cString = CStr(Data(r, UNIQUE_COLUMN_INDEX))
        If IsDate(Data(r, DATE_COLUMN_INDEX)) Then
            If IsNumeric(Data(r, TIME_COLUMN_INDEX)) Then IsValid = True
        End If
        If IsValid Then
            cValue = Data(r, DATE_COLUMN_INDEX) + Data(r, TIME_COLUMN_INDEX)
            IsValid = False
        Else
            cValue = 0
        End If
        If dict.Exists(cString) Then
            If cValue <= dict(cString)(2) Then DontWrite = True
        End If
        If DontWrite Then
            DontWrite = False
        Else
            Arr(1) = r
            Arr(2) = cValue
            dict(cString) = Arr
        End If
    Next r
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    
    If COPY_VALUES_ONLY Then ' only values (fast)
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            sr = dict(Key)(1)
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        Next Key
        For r = dr + 1 To rCount
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(r, c) = Empty
            Next c
        Next r
        rg.Value = Data
    Else ' values, formatting, formulas (slow)
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            sr = dict(Key)(1)
            dr = dr + 1
            rg.Rows(sr).Copy rg.Rows(dr)
        Next Key
        If rCount > dr Then
            rg.Resize(rCount - dr).Offset(dr).Clear
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```